# rake aborted! uninitialized constant User::UserGroup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake-task

I am having a strange problem where my rake task is running on my local machine but not in production. Getting the following error when try the same in PRODUCTION

> rake aborted!uninitialized constant User::UserGroup

when I ran the trace on it got following output

> $ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake billing:invoices --trace

```
** Invoke billing:invoices (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute billing:invoices
Building invoices
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant User::UserGroup
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:1205:in `compute_type'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:162:in `klass'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb:2107:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1984:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1984:in `build_join_association'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1948:in `build'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1956:in `block in build'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1955:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1955:in `build'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1852:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:246:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:246:in `build_joins'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:176:in `build_arel'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:149:in `arel'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:51:in `find_in_batches'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:20:in `find_each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => billing:invoices
```

The strange part is It is working all OK on my Local machine. Any suggestions ?

Comment: In my rake task I am using the environment variable task :invoices => :environment do

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have just added a migration called something like `20120221123456_users.rb`, and within it, you have:

```
class SomeNameThatsNotUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  ...
```

When Rails executes a migration, it expects to execute the file, which defines the class, and then instantiate the class, and call #up or #down on that class instance. How does Rails know what class to instantiate? It's supposed to correspond with the part of the file name following the numeric prefix and underscore, so for a file name like `20120221123456_users.rb`, the class name must be `Users`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the rake task source code that is failing?

Usually you need to write something like this (to avoid having issues with AR):

desc "My Task description"
  task :my_task_name => :environment do
    # Task code here
  end

Comment: Thanks @rorra fixed the issue by changing this in my config/production.rb file from  this config.threadsafe! unless ENV['THREADSAFE'] == 'off', to this --config.threadsafe!, config.dependency_loading = true if rails_rake_task. But still unclear with this what this will do ?